# Que deberia hacer con mis contenedores de Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

estoy montando un pequeño servidor de CI/CD y para esto decidí utilizar Jenkins y Docker . Ya realice todas las configuraciones necesarias en mi pipeline de Jenkins. Compilo y corro perfectamente mi app despegaba en Docker.

La cuestión es que quiero , que cada vez que vuelva a correr mi job en Jenkins , la nueva imagen que se genere de Docker se publique exactamente en mismo puerto de la anterior , ya que este puerto lo tengo expuesto en una IP pública .

Cómo lo tengo ahorita no puedo , pues porque si existe una primera versión de mi app corriendo en el 4040  , cuando valla a correr de nuevo mi job y le diga a la imagen que se exponga en el mismo puerto 4040, me aparece como error que el puerto está ocupado.

Existe alguna forma de detener o matar mi anterior contenedor que está corriendo en el 4040 , para que el nuevo quedé en ese puerto.

O si proponen una solución mejor me pueden decir , soy nuevo en devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el paso del deploy antes de lanzar el contenedor debes chequear si ya hay un contenedor leventado, luego si está levantado proceder a eliminarlo, finalmente levantar el nuevo contendor. Esto lo puedes solucionar con scripting, pero para ello algo importante aquí es que el contenedor que levantas en el puerto 4040 tenga siempre un **nombre** (Eso le pones siempre al lanzar: docker run --rm **--name=miaplicacion** -p 4040:4040 imagen).

Entonces el script que te ayudaría sería el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

state_container=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} miaplicacion)

if $state_container;
then
        docker rm -f miaplicacion
fi

docker run -d --name=miaplicacion \
        --restart=always \
        -p 4040:4040 imagen
```

Este script siempre verifica si hay un contenedor corriendo con el nombre **miaplicacion**, si es verdadero lo elimina y luego procede a lanzar el contenedor

Comment: Muchas gracias , perfecto lo que necesitaba

Comment: Genial, porfa puedes marcar que esta respuesta te ha sido útil. Saludos